# Azure DevOps Server 2020 - Missing Organisation Settings

Tags: azure-devops-server-2020

We are using Azure DevOps Server 2020, last year we migrated this from TFS 2018. After upgrade no one is able to see Organisation Settings option.
I am part of TFS administrator and TFS power users.

Any way to revert it back. We are upgrading this to 2022. The issue is same on our preprd environment where I upgraded to 2022.

I can only see collections settings

[image]

Tried restarting collection and checked all groups I am already part of Project Admin